# npx package using utf-8 in git bash

Tags: node.js, bash, git, npm, npx

I'm using git bash on windows 10 to run Node js with nvm (node version manager) and I have a problem with the npx package. For some reason npx has utf-8 encoding in it's output in cli containing cyrillic characters which git bash displays like this:

```
╨Э╤Г╨╢╨╜╨╛ ╤Г╨║╨░╨╖╨░╤В╤М ╨║╨╛╨╝╨░╨╜╨┤╤Г
```

I've tried installing different versions on node and npm and I've tried installing them without nvm. Node and npm use only English, but npx installs each time with cyrillic locale.

Is there a way to change npx locale, or fix it's rendering in git bash? Thanks!

Comment: Can you switch to code page 65001, perhaps before starting Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Bash designed mainly for Git. Therefore, using Git Bash for running `npm` (node command) is not really good practice.

Use CMD and no problem happen.

Comment: That is not really true. The Git Bash is an installation of MinGW. I use this for almost everything shell-like. With npx the problem for me is that sometimes you get options to select with cursor thtat do not work.